# How to set who to send email to?

Tags: webos

I have this script here:

```
function MainAssistant(argFromPusher) {
}

MainAssistant.prototype = {
    setup: function() {
        Ares.setupSceneAssistant(this);
    },
    cleanup: function() {
        Ares.cleanupSceneAssistant(this);
    },
    button6Tap: function(inSender, event) {

    },
    contactMe: function(inSender, event) {
        this.$.launchEmail1.launch();
    },
    launchEmail1Success: function(inSender, inResponse, inRequest) {

    }
};
```

I see in the documents you can use `recipients` but i don't understand how to use it. I know its a pram, but how do i use it.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find some hints [here](https://developer.palm.com/distribution/viewtopic.php?f=55&t=10619) at the webOS developer forum.

Basically:

```
this.$.launchEmail1.setRecipients({
              type:"email",
              role:1,
              value:"address@email.com",
              contactDisplay:"Your name"
          });
this.$.launchEmail1.setSubject("I have a question!");
```

Comment: It doesn't like to use the `value:"email@email.com"` information. just leaves the `To` section of the email application blank. The `this.$.launchEmail1.setSubject("I have a question!");
` works perfect though.